# How to disable MTP and PTP file sharing via USB on Android 5?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb-connection-mode

For privacy and security reasons I'd like to disable MTP and PTP on my phone. I recently plugged my phone into an inflight entertainment system to charge it, and was surprised to see that the status bar showed that the phone was connected as a camera (via PTP). This could happen with basically any USB hub, and you won't know until you connect to it.

Running Android 5.0.2 on a Samsung Galaxy A3 (SM-A300FU).

---

I have tried [the following](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/45211/5934):

1. Enabled USB debugging
2. Plugged in the USB cable
3. [Rooted my phone](http://www.all-things-android.com/content/how-root-samsung-mobile-device) (and verified that it's actually rooted)
4. `adb shell su -c 'setprop persist.sys.usb.config adb'` (thanks [@Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136435/how-to-disable-mtp-and-ptp-file-sharing-via-usb-on-android-5#comment173101_136435))
5. Verified in Terminal Emulator:

   ```
   $ su sh -c 'cat /data/property/persist.sys.usb.config'
   adb
   ```
6. Unplugged the USB cable
7. Rebooted
8. Disabled USB debugging
9. Plugged in the USB cable

At this point the device is automatically "Connected as a media device", and the setting is back to the default:

```
$ su sh -c 'cat /data/property/persist.sys.usb.config'
mtp
```

If I leave the USB debugging enabled the value is `mtp,adb` after rebooting.

---

After reporting this as a bug, it turns out it's actually been fixed, and [charge-only mode has been reintroduced in Android 6](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200499).

---

This is different from [Disabling MTP/PTP/all USB stuff except charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70225/disabling-mtp-ptp-all-usb-stuff-except-charging) because that question is about CyanogenMod, not stock Android, and the accepted answer is not applicable to Android 5.

Comment: Only the tags [tag:usb-connection-mode] and [tag:5.0-lollipop] are enough IMO.

Comment: You *incorrectly* followed the procedure. The command is `adb shell su -c 'setprop persist.sys.usb.config adb'`. This command runs with root privileges and makes the changes persistent. *Yours doesn't make it persistent.* The file `/data/property/persist.sys.usb.config` store the changes.

Comment: I see. Can you list and give us the contents of that file after reboot is performed? Which device is it?

Comment: Can you try with USB debugging already disabled and editing the file using a file explorer or text editor? Replace `mtp` with `none`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling MTP/PTP/all USB stuff except charging](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70225/disabling-mtp-ptp-all-usb-stuff-except-charging)

Comment: @Firelord This is not a duplicate, as explained above. Basically this question needs different answers for Android 3 and/or 4 (just set it to "Charge Only" mode), CyanogenMod (uncheck the connection modes you're not going to be using), Android 5, and Android 6 (once again set to "Charge Only" mode).

Answer (score 2):

[Thanks to @Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136435/how-to-disable-mtp-and-ptp-file-sharing-via-usb-on-android-5?noredirect=1#comment173109_136435), this is the procedure to follow:

1. Root your phone
2. Install [Terminal Emulator](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=jackpal.androidterm)
3. In Terminal Emulator, run `su sh -c 'echo -n none > /data/property/persist.sys.usb.config'`
4. Restart the phone

Bonus: Now you can get rid of all those horrible vendor apps. Bye Samsung and Three!

Caveat 1: **USB debugging no longer works after doing this**, regardless of whether you left it enabled while following the instructions or disabled and re-enabled it. All you need to do (I just verified it) is to set the value back to `adb` to make it work again, but then of course you have the original problem. If there’s a magic string to make USB debugging work and *simultaneously* disable both MTP and PTP, I don’t know what it is (I tried with `none,adb`).

Caveat 2: **You can’t update Android anymore without completely resetting your device.** Not even de-rooting and a factory reset work - bloody Android still says I’ve made an “unauthorized modification.” Let’s recap: “Freedom 0: The freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose.” I had to boot into Windows and use Samsung Smart Switch for PC to upgrade.

Comment: If you one day find the magic string, don't forget to update your answer. I just ended up the same: needing ADB, I had to leave it on "mtp,adb".

Comment: You can also just set `adb` mode alone. Instead of `none`, just use `adb`. That won't show MTP/PTP

Comment: I agree with @GokulNC. Setting `adb` alone works well in CM and stock Android.

Comment: @GokulNC @Firelord As I said above setting it to simply `adb` doesn't work - it's overridden to `mtp,adb`.