# Prevent USB data transfer (when phone is in use) and being charged

Tags: applications, usb, security, charging

I would like to know how to protect my data when I use public battery charger in public places. I know that if I do not unlock my screen when  charging, my data is safe, but what if I would like to use my phone while connected to  public charger?

I would like to know how or if it requires to have an app that can help me block data transfer via USB , even if I am using the phone.

Comment: What Android version and what phone are you using? Some manufacturers as well as newer stock Android versions have this built in.

Comment: Android 4+ you could follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21712630/1757321

Comment: I got Samsung Dous2 (os 4.2) Samsung J7 / A5 (os 5.1). I have checked on USB connection setting but there are radio button to choose between MTP or PTP. None of option to turn off.

Comment: If possible, [switch to Marshmallow](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/127508/96277). Done. If the device is rooted, you can use [tag:automation] with this answer: [How to disable MTP and PTP file sharing via USB on Android 5?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/136441)

Comment: Thank you Firelord. However I do not want to rooted my phone, because I have read that if phone is rooted, some apps can retrieve password's account from the phone. I think it does not safe.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing your question to ask for ways to achieve and not just seek for an app solution, so that the question is not closed on account of seeking app recommendation.

Comment: How about just turning your device off when charging.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** While reading up on this after answering, stumbled upon the name for this threat- [Juice Jacking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juice_jacking), defined as (emphasis added)

> Juice jacking is a term used to describe a cyber attack where wherein malware might be installed on to, or data surreptitiously copied from, a **smart phone**, tablet or other computer device using a **charging port** that doubles as a data connection, typically over USB.

Further, *mitigation* section of wiki says

> Juice jacking is **not possible** if a device is charged via the AC adapter shipped with the device, a battery backup device, or by **utilizing a USB cable that has its data cables removed**

- The simplest way would be to use a cable that only charges but does not allow data transfer. Such a cable is *non-standard*, since it does not adhere to standards wherein **data connectors / cables also play an important role of negotiating the *power* requirements** (1)
- These cables come with a disadvantage- charging speed is **very slow** (often by a factor of 10x as reported in some forums). A work around is to buy a cable of 20 AWG thickness (2)  Since 20 AWG is the thickest cable permitted and by virtue of its thickness offers least resistance , and therefore faster charging.  Such cables are available on [ebay](http://m.ebay.com/itm/High-Speed-Charge-Only-Micro-USB-2m-Charging-Cable-Android-Quality-Fast-Charger-/221266793926) as an example. While these cables may charge at a reasonable rate, they are not recommended for regular use, as charging current rate is constant and not negotiable (as desired by battery charging logic)

**Other Possible Methods**

1. **adb commands/ tweaking your system OS:** These may or may not work since it is highly dependent on the way device OS is designed. To get a flavor, see my [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133984/131553) , which is the opposite of what you want to achieve.

**Edit:** Thanks to Firelord's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/226842/131553), found a way that hasn't been documented anywhere AFAIK.

> You can run this command:
>
> > `adb shell svc usb setFunctions`
> > This should reset the USB mode/configuration to *charging only*.

2. **DIY methods modifying the cable or end connectors:**  **Not recommended** unless you have a good knowledge and are adept at such tinkering. For example,  [How-to-make-a-USB-no-data-charger-cable](http://m.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-USB-no-data-charger-cable/)- Google search will give you many more
3. **USB Condoms:**  I didn't make that up :). These are  implementation of DIY methods, sold as ready for use.  [SyncStop/ USB condom](http://syncstop.com/) is one such product- many are available

**Note:**  All above methods result in **sub optimal charging** and IMO not recommended for regular use since **charging power can't be negotiated**

Interestingly, there is a product [Charging Safely over USB](http://www.reclaimerlabs.com/blog/2015/6/2/charging-safely-over-usb) marketed last year (currently out of stock as per website). This recognises that doing away with data connectors is a *bad idea*, and **permits power negotiation** to happen (although slowly) while **denying data transfer**  by using capacitors to limit bandwidth only for power negotiation

**Bottom Line**  Use 20 AWG cable recommended right on top, and as sparingly as possible

---

(1):  [USB charging specifications](http://www.usb.org/developers/powerdelivery/) in conjunction with [Battery Charging Revision 1.2](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5801) lays down " *standard for establishing the proper way to charge a battery from a USB port* "

(2):  [American Wire Gauge (AWG)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) is a reference for thickness of cables. In this system, **larger numbers indicate thinner wires.** USB specification above makes reference to AWG numbers of 20, 22, 24, 26 and 28

Comment: Is it not possible to use a powerboat ( spare battery) and charge that from the unsafe source and then later charge your phone from the bank

Comment: @Willemien: Of course, it is another possibility but the question talks of directly charging. Yes, you have a point . Thanks