# Is it possible to disable USB tethering from command line?

Tags: adb, settings, command-line

I try to be able to stop USB tethering.

I tried:

```
adb shell am stop com.android.settings/.TetherSettings # Unknown command: stop
adb shell am kill com.android.settings/.TetherSettings # nothing
adb shell service call connectivity 33 i32 0 s16 text  # works
```

Latest works, but I don't know if it's very reliable like `am` commands

Related, but the opposite, [Is it possible to activate the "USB Tethering" Android setting from the command line?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29954/is-it-possible-to-activate-the-usb-tethering-android-setting-from-the-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this command:

```
adb shell svc usb setFunctions
```

This should reset the USB mode/configuration to *charging only*.